# How can I navigate my site through rspec/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

I am learning about search engine optimisation and would like to carry out some basic SEO tests on my rails site. This will involve things like checking for unique titles, alt text on images, etc.

Before I can do this, I need to be able to navigate my site. I can do this manually by defining all of the visitable routes, but I was wondering if there's a way to automate this through rspec and capybara? Perhaps I could use the routes file, or some kind of sitemap gem?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: That's what Capybara is. You can click links, find text, even run javascript (if you use something like Selenium).

Comment: Yes, but how can I automate this to visit every accessible page on my site? I guess I should look into parsing a sitemap or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a view test using rspec:

```
scenario 'autocompletes contact name', js: true do
  visit new_communication_path
  fill_in 'communication_contact_id', with: 'Joh'
  page.should have_content 'John Doe'

  find('#ui-id-2').click

  find('#communication_contact_id').value.should == 'John Doe'
  find('#contact_autocomplete_target', visible: false).value.should ==     contact.id.to_s
 end
```

What it does:
1) visits rails page (uses firefox as engine)
2) find field and fill in Joh in that field
3) check if the page has the words John Doe
4) click element with id listed above
etc..

Gems include
rspec-rails
capybara
selenium-webdriver

To visit every page just repeat the process by iterating through 'rails routes'
example:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a.each do |route|
 visit route
end
```

Hope this helps.